# Could roses be used to fence a dog in?

Tags: dogs, containment

We are looking at buying a new house and would like a large yard for our dog to play in.  I've never cared for most fences aesthetically, and they are extremely expensive/difficult to install.  This morning I began wandering about a different possibility.

If a series of trellises were setup in a line around the yard (where the fence would go), and climbing roses planted all along, would the thorns act as sufficient deterrent for our dog?  I understand this relies heavily on our dogs personality, and I believe she'd be susceptible to this sort of barrier, but I'm curious if it's ever been tried before or if studies have been done on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No,

First hedges grow much denser than rose bushes, and thorns are not an effective deterrent for a dog. Even a fence is not always a good means of containing a dog, who is determined to leave.  I have new neighbors who moved into house with a 40 year old hedge as a fence, it was about a week before the first dog went through the hedge, and their dogs are always supervised when they are outside.

These related questions discuss alternatives to fences

- [Preventing dog from going to highway](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/)
- [Is overhead cable running leash suitable for all dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2527/)
- [How can I keep my dog in my back yard?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/)

There are several options for using plants to disguise a fence, but these will require first a fence appropriate for containing your dog, and then years for the plants to grow sufficiently to cover the fence.

I looked for studies about containing dogs with plant growth and came up empty. I did find a 1845 work in [Blackwood's Edinburgh magazine, Volume 57](http://books.google.com/books?id=B_dFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA306&dq=hedge+as+a+dog+fence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5I5oVJbSFIWvyATbvIKoCQ&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=hedge%20as%20a%20dog%20fence&f=false), that talks about dogs and hedges as fences, while it does not give much information about keeping a dog in, it does speak abut the years required to make a hedge to contain livestock (which is easier than containing a dog).

[image: Digging dog]

[image: Climbing Dog]

If you have a dog who is too timid to test boundaries.  Who might possibly be contained by a minimalist boundary divider, and if that dog is **EVER** going to be unsupervised in the yard, than you need a fences capable of keeping out all of the neighborhood dogs and wild life that can harm your dog.

For small dogs see the related question https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6785

Comment: Thank you; that's great information (and I love the pictures :) ).  You make references to a dog that is determined to leave.  What if we have a dog who is a bit of a scaredy-cat and really doesn't push her bounds?  Do you know of any research/anecdotes about using thorns as a way to show a dog who respects their boundaries their boundaries?

Comment: @Nicholas If your dog truly respects and understands the property boundaries, you don't need any fence (Not a Suggested solution).  If your dog is always supervised and on a leash you don't need a fence.  If your dog is ever outside alone, and is a "scaredy-cat" than you need a fence sufficient to keep other animals out.

Comment: It could be used as a marker for an invisible fence line, but a fence also works better to keep things out of the yard.